# How to help almost 2-year-old stay asleep after traumatic experience?

Tags: toddler, sleep

My daughter is 1 year and 10 months old. She went through her first ever trauma when she had a seizure out of random. Now, we're at home and she's having a hard time staying asleep. All she wants is daddy to hold her and I had only 1/2 an hour of sleep and I have to be at work at 6 am, that's 2 1/2 hours away. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it was a traumatic experience for you as well. Children are more resilient than parents and your daughter should recover from the scary experience quickly. It is important to try and focus on keeping yourself calm. If you can, take the day off work. If not remember that you can persevere through a short period of poor rest. Try to get back to or establish a bedtime routine that helps you both unwind.